# Expression must have class type

Tags: c++, class, new-operator

I have't coded in c++ for some time and I got stuck when I tried to compile this simple snippet:

```
class A
{
  public:
    void f() {}
};

int main()
{
  {
    A a;
    a.f(); // works fine
  }

  {
    A *a = new A();
    a.f(); // this doesn't
  }
}
```

Comment: the line that says "this doesn't" is actually OK, making your question look confusing.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

It's a pointer, so instead try:

```
a->f();
```

Basically the operator `.` (used to access an object's fields and methods) is used on objects and references, so:

```
A a;
a.f();
A& ref = a;
ref.f();
```

If you have a pointer type, you have to dereference it first to obtain a reference:

```
A* ptr = new A();
(*ptr).f();
ptr->f();
```

The `a->b` notation is usually just a shorthand for `(*a).b`.

#### A note on smart pointers

The `operator->` can be overloaded, which is notably used by smart pointers. When [you're using smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one), then you also use `->` to refer to the pointed object:

```
auto ptr = make_unique<A>();
ptr->f();
```

Comment: Just starting out C++, still have to make it an automatism to figure out whether to use a pointer or a reference. In my particular case all I needed was a reference, but for some reason I passed a pointer instead. Anyway, thanks for the clear explanation !

Answer (score 17):

Allow an analysis.

```
#include <iostream>   // not #include "iostream"
using namespace std;  // in this case okay, but never do that in header files

class A
{
 public:
  void f() { cout<<"f()\n"; }
};

int main()
{
 /*
 // A a; //this works
 A *a = new A(); //this doesn't
 a.f(); // "f has not been declared"
 */ // below


 // system("pause");  <-- Don't do this. It is non-portable code. I guess your 
 //                       teacher told you this?
 //                       Better: In your IDE there is prolly an option somewhere
 //                               to not close the terminal/console-window.
 //                       If you compile on a CLI, it is not needed at all.
}
```

As a general advice:

```
0) Prefer automatic variables
  int a;
  MyClass myInstance;
  std::vector<int> myIntVector;

1) If you need data sharing on big objects down 
   the call hierarchy, prefer references:

  void foo (std::vector<int> const &input) {...}
  void bar () { 
       std::vector<int> something;
       ...
       foo (something);
  }


2) If you need data sharing up the call hierarchy, prefer smart-pointers
   that automatically manage deletion and reference counting.

3) If you need an array, use std::vector<> instead in most cases.
   std::vector<> is ought to be the one default container.

4) I've yet to find a good reason for blank pointers.

   -> Hard to get right exception safe

       class Foo {
           Foo () : a(new int[512]), b(new int[512]) {}
           ~Foo() {
               delete [] b;
               delete [] a;
           }
       };

       -> if the second new[] fails, Foo leaks memory, because the
          destructor is never called. Avoid this easily by using 
          one of the standard containers, like std::vector, or
          smart-pointers.
```

As a rule of thumb: If you need to manage memory on your own, there is generally a superiour manager or alternative available already, one that follows the RAII principle.

Answer (score 11):

**Summary**: Instead of `a.f();` it should be `a->f();`

In main you have defined **a** as a pointer to *object of* **A**, so you can access functions using the `->` operator.

An *alternate*, but less readable way is `(*a).f()`

`a.f()` could have been used to access f(), if **a** was declared as:
`A a;`

Answer (score 7):

`a` is a pointer. You need to use`->`, not `.`